Как передать в запущенный тобой процесс сигнал и получить его в этом процессе?
Работаю на Orange Pi Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Я реализовал sip клиент на языке c на основе библиотеки pjsip, используя pjsua. Запускаю этот клиент с требованием позвонить на номер из скрипта на python используя os.system(cmd_to_run_sip_client). Если абонент завершает вызов, то sip-клиент завершает свою работу. А вот вопрос, как из скрипта на python сказать sip-клиенту - заверши вызов и заверши свою работу? Т.е. мне не просто нужно замочить процесс клиента, а передать ему требование завершить свою работу.
Я могу, например, из скрипта создать файл с некоторым содержимым, а клиент будет сканировать нужную директорию на наличие этого файла, и если найдёт его, то сбросит вызов и завершит свою работу. Но наверняка есть более удобное и изящное решение, которое не потребляет ресурс карты памяти

Можно например через os.pipe() клиент открывать и общаться с ним в обе стороны. Вроде бы. Надо ещё почитать, может там в одну сторону только общение. Но общение есть.

@CrazyElf спасибо, посмотрю в эту сторону. Забыл указать, что клиент написан на языке c.

@CrazyElf я не понял, как pipe может быть полезен в моём случае. Создавая pipe я получаю 2 дескриптора, в которые могу писать с основного процесса и читать из дочернего. Но код, отвечающий за sip-клиент находится вообще в другом месте. И мне не ясно, как там я могу получить этот дескриптор, который нужно читать?

Для вызываемого клиента это будут кажется stdin и stdout. Ну, возможно, это тоже не совсем то. Я до конца вашу задачу не понял. Ещё есть subprocess.run примерно про тоже самое. Просто os.system вообще никак не общается с подпроцессом, а эти хоть как-то.

Задача - скрипт запустил клиент и ждёт подходящего времени. Затем в нужный момент посылает клиенту команду - бросай всё, иди отдыхай. Понимаю, канал, по которому будет идти команда на отбой, надо создать в момент запуска клиента и в этот же момент передать ему. Чтоб клиенту сразу было ясно, куда смотреть.

Интересно, а можно через аргумент передать клиенту дескриптор на чтение?

@CrazyElf ChatGPT подсказал мне про именованный канал. Это похоже на то, что я искал

Ну и хорошо. pipe это тоже канал, но только на уровне потоков ввода-вывода. Именованный канал тут возможно и правда больше подходит.

возможно, тебя могут также заинтересовать сигналы ядра Linux. Работа с ними очень хорошо описана в книге Майкла Керриска "Linux API", по оглавлению можно найти

@Lebchik благодарю за наводку, посмотрю
